# Firefox scroll bars but not on Chrome while loading a video in iframe

Tags: video-streaming, scrollbar, iframe-resizer

I'm having trouble finding while loading a remote video in Iframe . On Firefox, it's showing side scrolling to the right but on Chrome its working fine
css for video is as follows

## remoteVideo { right: 0; bottom: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }

Comment: Needs more detail.  I would at the very least include the HTML as well.  Perhaps an export from the developer consoles css panel to show all the CSS applied to the element.

Comment: #videos{
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

#remoteVideo { right: 0; bottom: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }       <div id="videos" >
   
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay playsinline style="overflow: auto;"></video>
   
</div>
  \

Comment: Edit your original post and put it in there, people often won't read down to the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Overflow should be set to hidden, not auto